# Gender interaction rules for Asexuals?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, muslim-practices, men-women

I am an asexual. Means I don't feel any attraction at all to any gender and physical intercourse seems kinda gross to me :v.

**Now are there any exceptions to be made in the Islamic Rules for gender interactions in my case?**
To put it in **context**,I got some female 'friends' from work & study whom I talk to on a near daily basis. I never touch them(hugging, shaking hands), avoid khalwa(seclusion) as much as possible, don't talk anything vulgar/flirtatiously; basically I don't go overboard and don't even want to. But we do talk about common interests, necessary stuff and in rare cases about personal life & all.

I have heard throughout Islamic history men who couldn't be attracted to women were employed in the Harem but those were mostly chastised men(not similar to me).